# Jquery animation and mobile phone

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made an animation with jquery of 3 divs that fade in and some h3 that come from the left and stay in the middle of the screen but when I resize the window let's say to mobile phone dimentions the letters don't stop at the middle but keep on going and i looks prety bad.

Also since I use bootstrap my nav bar becomes small and makes you click on a button that has a dropdown now if I click there the h3 paragraph insted of staying at the place of that it is on the div it goes up (it dosn't follow the div but it stays at a specific part of the screen).

This is what I currently have:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#div1").fadeIn(5000, function() {
    $(".what").animate({
      "left": "45%"
    }, 1300);
  });
  $("#div2").fadeIn(3000);
  $("#div3").fadeIn(1500);
});
```

```css
#what {
  position: absolute;
  left: -40%;
  top: 130px;
}

#div1 {
  display: none;
}

#div2 {
  display: none;
}

#div3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<div id="div1" class="container-fluid bg-1 text-center">
  <h3><a id="what" class="margin what">What Am I?</h3></a>
    <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/fEchLa/e.jpg" class="img-responsive img-
    circle margin kuklos" style="display:inline" alt="Me" width="350" height="650">
    <h3>I'm A Young Freelancer.</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify exactly what you want us to help you with.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving #div1 {position: relative; width: 100%}